# Installation Python 3.6.x on Windows using command line installer (without GUI)

Tags: python

I need to installed Python 3.6.x on Windows as part of an automated process without user-interaction. Recently Python releases provided MSI files for installation using the "msiexec" utility however there are no more MSI release files available for Python 3.6.X. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 9):

As you correctly stated, Python 3.6 no longer has MSI installers available.

However, the setup PE has command line switches that will let you install silently without GUI.
`/quiet` will install with default options without showing the GUI.

See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html (section 3.1.4) for a full list of options.

Comment: the undocumented silent `/repair` flag is also nice to know about, in case you wish to fix python installations that have missing files.